How to make color not spread in gradient in jetpack compose?
I want a box that is 70% red and 30% blue (vertically).
CSS equivalent would be(Test here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 0 70%, red 70% 100%)

What I Do not want to do -
Column(){
  Box(modifier.backgroud(blue).height(70.df))
  Box(modifier.backgroud(red).height(30.df))
}

Because, Inside the Box, there is a piece of code for drawing a graph.
Basically I want the graph to have red background below 30 unit in y-axis(0-100) and above it blue background

Box with 70% blue and 30% red.

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    0.7f to Color.Blue,
                    0.3f to Color.Red,
                )
            )
    )

